# Alternatives to model classes in Rails migrations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, rails-migrations

The Rails style guide [says](https://github.com/bbatsov/rails-style-guide#migrations)

> Don't use model classes in migrations. The model classes are constantly evolving and at some point in the future migrations that used to work might stop, because of changes in the models used.

How do I change data with migrations (a practice some criticise, but is being used in the project I'm working on) while keeping this advice in mind?

Comment: @DaveSchweisguth it's not bad, but doesn't feel like it explains everything.

Comment: Hmmm. I think those are all of my major model class pain points. If I think of any more I'll add to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use old plain SQL to migrate the data (SQL is a very powerful language to process stuff!).

Another solution can be to use a standalone Model, like suggested in [rubocop](https://github.com/rubocop-hq/rails-style-guide#define-model-class-migrations) or this [other article](https://blog.makandra.com/2010/03/how-to-use-models-in-your-migrations-without-killing-kittens/):

```
class MigrationProduct < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = :products
end

def up
  MigrationProduct.where(status: old_status).update_all(status: new_status)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You could address the issue without following the actual advice. I do use model classes in my migrations, but I use a couple of strategies to prevent changes in models from breaking my migrations:

- I periodically dump a fully migrated copy of my schema into db/schema.rb and delete my migrations. Of course one can do this only after all migrations have been run on every environment that they need to be run on. New databases will be created already migrated, which is both faster and eliminates incompatibility between migrations and current model code.
- When I need to use schema changed in an earlier migration right away in the same migration run, I reload the model definition with `Model.reset_column_information`.

Or you could take that advice and just use `execute` to execute SQL in your migrations. I don't do that if I can avoid it, since it's usually less effort to use model methods.